# Is it possible to indent the content thats added to files by SaltStack

Tags: jinja2, indentation, salt-stack

I would like to have the content I append to the file, to be indented, so it's more readable:

```
configure_max_upload:
  file.line:
    - name: /etc/apache2/sites-available/{{ pillar['apache']['domain'] }}.conf
    - mode: ensure
    - after: "php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir .*"
    - indent: True
    - content: |
        php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 64M
        php_admin_value post_max_size 64M
        php_admin_value max_execution_time 300
        php_admin_value max_input_time 300
    - require:
      - pkg: php_modules
```

At the moment the output of this command looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/peter/htdocs
    ServerName www.example.com

    <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
      AssignUserId peter peter
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "/var/www/peter/logs/access.log" combined
    ErrorLog "/var/www/peter/logs/error.log"

    php_admin_value error_log "/var/www/peter/logs/phperrors.log"
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/peter/tmp/"
php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_admin_value post_max_size 64M
php_admin_value max_execution_time 300
php_admin_value max_input_time 300
...
```

Can someone help me, I think there surely is a easy way.
Thank you

Comment: can you try `|+` instead of `|` for multiine text?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work